# Why isn't my output showing after my switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, output

I'm learning Java right now and I've never used switch statements before. I tried to enter a simple charmed quiz, but something in the switch statement isn't working.

I've tried putting text at various points in the program to test if the program every reaches that code. I have a good response inside the actual switch, so If I answer Question 1 wrong the text prompt will show up. But any later than inside the switch statement and none of my scoring output appears until all iterations of the for loop are complete. I have tried moving the "correct/incorrect" output to various points and none of them seem to work.

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter your name!");
String name = myScanner.nextLine();
int wrongCounter = 0;
boolean correctChecker = false;
int score = 0;
String answer;

System.out.println("Welcome to the Charmed Quiz, " + name + "!");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (wrongCounter < 4) {
        switch(i) {
        case 0: 
            System.out.println("Who read the spell that gave the Charmed Ones their powers?");
            System.out.println("Enter your answer");

            answer = myScanner.nextLine();

            switch (answer) {
            case "Pheobe":
                correctChecker = true;
                break;
            default:
                correctChecker = false;
                break;
            }
        case 1:
            System.out
                    .println("Who travelled to a cursed town with Prue when Pheobe was shot in a premonition?");
            System.out.println("Enter your answer");

            answer = myScanner.nextLine();

            switch (answer) {
            case "Cole":
                correctChecker = true;
                break;
            default:
                correctChecker = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
    

    if (correctChecker == true) {
        score++;
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    } else {
        wrongCounter++;
        System.out.println("Incorrect!");

    }
```

Comment: You seem to be using the [for-switch loop antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence). I'd recommend learning away from that kind of design, and using methods instead. The usages of `switch` here are poor and forced (there's no use in having a switch for a correct/incorrect answer).

Comment: `correctChecker = "Pheobe".equals(answer);` -- you don't need any kind of branching statement to determine if one `String` is equal to another. Nesting `switch` statements is *confusing*.

Comment: I'm only using this program to learn how to use the switch. I've never used a switch statement, I've always ignored it because I didn't think it was the best way to handle most situations I have encountered. I still want to figure out how to use it effectively in case I need it in the future.

Comment: It's working now. I did switch it away from the nested switch statements, but at least the inner and outer commands will help me do that if I need to in the future. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely isn't the best way of achieving a quiz game, but if you're using this as a learning exercise then the best course of action is to take the advice from @rzwitserloot.

Add a break after your main switch statement cases as opposed to the inner switch statement.

There is no real use having an inner switch statement though when you can use `correctChecker = "Pheobe".equals(answer);` to get a true or false boolean value in a single line.

This just means you can avoid the second switch statement which makes it way less confusing.

Altogether your cases could look something like this:

```
    case 0: 
        System.out.println("Who read the spell that gave the Charmed Ones their powers?");
        System.out.println("Enter your answer");

        answer = myScanner.nextLine();
        correctChecker = "Pheobe".equals(answer);
        break;
        
        }
```

In future, it would be better to store questions and answers in an array and use the for loop to iterate through that. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=686&v=nCIjHTlztNg&feature=emb_title) is a good tutorial on the subject.

Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Thank you! I am just using this as a way to try the switch code. I've never used a switch statement and I'm trying to get a grip on how it works. I appreciate your reply.

Comment: I didn't even think of the correctChecker = "Phoebe".equals(answer); That's a great way to cut this cumbersome code.

Comment: @ChristinaDeRyke For obvious reasons, it's called a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many problems with this code. The primary issue is that `break` breaks the closest construct it can break, which in your case is the **inner** `switch`. Whereas your intent is clearly to break out of both. Either [A] add another `break` right before the `case 1:` statement, or [B] use a labelled break; put something like `outer:` *before* the first (primary/outer) `switch`, and then make all those statements `break outer;`.

But, really, none of this (either the outer or the inner) are in any way sensible in switch form. I get that this is a learning exercise, but I'd think of something else to learn with.

Also, it's Phoebe, not Pheobe.

Comment: Thank you for the outer/break outer. That helped me get to the tutorials I need to figure this out. I know the code is overly cumbersome, I have found that I learn best by repeating the same thing over and over. All of my programs to learn a new concept are a big absurd.

Comment: And I've never been able to spell that name right :)